# How to use the Preferences layouts to get a consistent look-and-feel without using SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-theme

I've been looking for a brainless way to build up an interface, preferably by invoking default, built-in layouts and styling.

The way that android preferences are set up (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) is exactly what I was hoping to find, except that it ALSO writes back to sharedPreferences. I don't want any of the actual settings-saving machinery (none of what I'm using it for is a global setting), but I still want to use the interface-construction machinery.

Is there some known, existing way to do this? Or, is there a known reason that it shouldn't be done?